# Timeout: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: vb.net

I am having a timeout issue.  The service that I am connecting with works fine when it responds in a timely fashion.  When it takes around 10 seconds, it times out with the exception.  Besides Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout, what other timeout properties can I set so that it waits properly?  Is there something I need to set at the TCP/IP level?  Thanks for your help.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Here is my code.  I have tried variations of many things:

```
'The post works
Dim _httpRequest As HttpWebRequest
_httpRequest = WebRequest.Create("mywebservice")
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
_httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
_httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10
'This is a 60 second wait
_httpRequest.Timeout = 60000 
'This is a 60 second wait
_httpRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000
_httpRequest.KeepAlive = False
_httpRequest.Method = "POST"

'If the response takes takes 10 seconds
'This is the message we get:  System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

_httpRequest.Method = "GET"
_httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
'The error is here
Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = _httpRequest.GetResponse
```

Comment: Have you checked the timeout settings in IIS? Or whatever web server you're using (you don't specify).

Comment: Melanie. Thanks for the quick response.  It is actually a local web service that is timing out.  We have a 3rd party service that we perform posts and gets to.  Example:  HTTP://10.10.50.28:22280/transaction/identifyCustomer

Comment: I'm afraid my idea on the timeout settings is all I got. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a machine.config setting I can set or app.config setting that I can set?  The connection is closing after 10 seconds even though I have set the timeout to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The `Timeout` value you are setting is 60000, which translates to about 1 minute, since `Timeout` value is in milliseconds. A value of 1000 is 1 second. 
So try setting it appropriately to a higher value. e.g. Try setting it to 5 or 10 minutes for a test.

Comment: That didn't help.  It is like the timeout is not recognized.  The connection closes after only 10 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you set `_httpRequest.KeepAlive = True`